# Check a concept against a type

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

How to get a core-constant expression of type bool from a concept and a type?

```
template<class T>
concept Valid = requires(T t) {
    { t.x };
};

struct ValidExample   { int x; };
struct InValidExample {};

static_assert(?); // ValidExample is Valid
static_assert(?); // InValidExample is not Valid
```

I'm starting to play with concepts, and I'd like to check a type against a concept (to be more precise: to define a trait from a concept). How to do so?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might use:

```
static_assert(Valid<ValidExample>); // ValidExample is Valid
static_assert(!Valid<InValidExample>); // InValidExample is not Valid
```

as template variables (of type `bool`).

Comment: <insert facepalm>

Comment: @YSC - Who'd have thought that the noisy `bool concept` syntax could have had actual value :)

Comment: @bartop: There's nothing strange about it. A concept is just a *variable template*. You access it like any other variable template.

Comment: @StoryTeller What value?

Comment: @Barry - Hints at the use as a boolean constant. It was meant to be ironic, tbh.